# Removing contents of a sting in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript array like this:

```
VirtualMachineByPhysicalMachine::GROUP-USER-DEV
,DRS-shou-2/domain-b/shou18lcorevc::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-b/core
,DRS-SQLCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.128
,DRS-WC2012test/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.129
,DRS-RAC/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.130
,DRS-RHELCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.131
,VirtualMachineByPhysicalMachine::GROUP-USER-PROD
,DRS-WC2008test/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.132
,DRS-SybaseCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.133
```

and I want to format the array as follow:

```
GROUP-USER-DEV
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-b/core
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.128
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.129
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.130
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.131
, GROUP-USER-PROD
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.132
, PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.133
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var arr =['VirtualMachineByPhysicalMachine::GROUP-USER-DEV'
,'DRS-shou-2/domain-b/shou18lcorevc::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-b/core'
,'DRS-SQLCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.128'
,'DRS-WC2012test/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.129'
,'DRS-RAC/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.130'
,'DRS-RHELCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.131'
,'VirtualMachineByPhysicalMachine::GROUP-USER-PROD'
,'DRS-WC2008test/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.132'
,'DRS-SybaseCluster/domain-c/10.128::PM-GROUP-DRS-domain-c/10.133'
]

var newArr= arr.map(function (anObj){
    return anObj.split("::")[1];

});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: that did work thanks my question is around how come the split works with split("::")[1];

Comment: split function parameter defines the delimiter.  it's :: in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably able to do something with a split.

Something like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].split("::")[1];
}
```